# Path to image by h:graphicImage JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, resources, prettyphoto

I am using h:graphicImage to display images using the `name` attribute. Now, in order to successfully implement [PrettyPhoto (JQuery implementation)](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/), I need the resulting path to the image (`/javax.faces.resource/pictures/file.png.xhtml`) as result in my `<a href />` too.

As you can see in from a snippet of PrettyPhoto's documentation, I will need the path to my image as the path for my `<a href />` (there's actually a difference due to the fact of using thumbnails):

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="This is the title" />
</a>
```

**Is there any way to extract the resourceName (as it is named for `h:graphicImage`) for my `h:outputLink`?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the implicit EL variable mapper `#{resource}` to convert a JSF resource library/name to full URL.

So, in your particular case,

```html
<h:outputLink value="#{resource['images/fullscreen/2.jpg']}">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" />
</h:outputLink>
```

If you're also using resource library, then the syntax should look like follows:

```html
<h:outputLink value="#{resource['default:images/fullscreen/2.jpg']}">
    <h:graphicImage library="default" name="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" />
</h:outputLink>
```

*(note that you can even just use `<a href>` instead of `<h:outputLink value>`)*

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you once again!

Comment: can you tell me how to access image from remote location in <h:graphicImage> ?